# Tensorflow: TensorBoard event dump encoding

Tags: tensorflow, events, encoding, dump, tensorboard

I tried to decode Tensorboard's event dump using `UTF-8` in a text editor, but it gives partially decoded data:

[image]

Atom suggested me to use `ISO-8859/2`, but that looked the same as well :( I also tried `UTF-16 LE` and `UTF-16 BE`, but failed to decode it.

I do understand that `FileWriter` may not write plain text, but isn't it possible at all to read it using a text editor?